# Is Windows 7 Home Premium edition sufficient for software development?

Tags: windows-7

Is the Windows 7 Home Premium sufficient for software development?

Development would be in Visual Studio 2010.

I'm on a budget so would rather purchase 'Home Premium' rather than 'Professional' or 'Ultimate'.

The [Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/compare/default.aspx) says there is next to nothing functionality wise between them that developers would miss. Can anyone confirm or deny?

BTW. Does it come with a version of IIS?

I realize that this is not a technical question. But it is important to me and I'm sure other developers wonder the same thing.

Cheers,

-- Lee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  I write software using VS 2010 in WIndows 7 Home Premium without any trouble.

Answer (score 8):

Basically, yes, it's totally sufficient.

A big upside to professional edition, though, is that it comes with [Windows XP mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx), essentially a virtual machine with a built-in XP installation (and included license). That can come in handy if you do web development (test things in IE6/7) or need to test applications in the old XP GUI.

Windows XP mode can also be a lifesaver if you need to run older applications that won't run properly in 7. I personally would consider choosing the Professional Edition for that reason.

Comment: Cheers Pekka, Though I tend to use Virtual PC and the Virtual Images that Microsoft provide for cross browser testing in IE6,IE7 and IE8.

Comment: @Lee that'll probably do then, if you don't need the seamless integration of XP apps that XP mode offers. You surely already know, but under no circumstances buy the boxed version, but the system builder one (I guess this works roughly the same way in the UK as it does in Germany, SB is up to 50% cheaper).

Comment: @Lee sorry, I just checked, seems to be a german thing - there was a court ruling saying that MS can't forbid OEM versions to be sold apart from hardware, which led to (legal) OEM versions being sold containing just the DVD and the key, which every sane person here buys now. I thought it was a MS worldwide thing.

Answer (score 8):

Don't purchase either, instead buy a [MAPS subscription](https://partner.microsoft.com/40016455) from them.  In the UK these cost  £199 p.a. (I imagine less in the states) for which you get virtually everything you're likely to need except Visual Studio.  Currently you get

- 10 licences for MS Office 2007
- 10 for Project
- 10 for Visio
- 10 for Outlook
- 10 for Mappoint (North America only)
- 1 for Office Communications Server plus 10 CALS
- 10 for Windows 7 Professional
- 1 for Windows 7 Ultimate
- 1 for Windows Server 2008 R2, plus 10 Server CALS and 10 Terminal Server CALS
- 1 for Windows Web Server 2008 R2
- 1 for Windows Home Server 2008 R2
- 1 for Windows Business Server
- 1 for Windows Exchange server plus 10 CALS
- 1 for Windows Office Sharepoint, plus 10 CALS
- 1 for WIndows SQL Server standard plus 10 CALS

Plus a bunchload of other odds and sods servers and products of lesser interest.

MAPS is such good value - and I'm by no means a Microsoft fan - that purchase is pretty much a no-brainer for any software developer who runs Windows in any form.

UPDATE: Since I wrote this Microsoft now offer a Developer version of MAPS which replaces some of the more esoteric servers with Visual Studio.  You still get the Office, Windows and SQL Server licences, which makes it just about perfect for any developer.

Comment: What a great tip. And it's even available in Germany. I will never buy anything else again. Thanks for pointing this out Cruachan.

Comment: Yep, I can't imagine why with this available to developers anyone would go any other route. They did try and raise the entry bar a year or two ago by insisting you did one or two online courses (free, took about an hour each) but they dropped that last year. That it's a yearly fee is a bit off putting I suppose, particularly in years when nothing much happens, but last year we had Windows 7 and this we'll get Office 2010 and the generosity of the number of licences they give you is excellent.  I run Macs and Linux machines too but MAPS has kept me on MS and recommending MS for many years.

Comment: Wow. The MAPS subscription looks awesome and so good value for money. I think I will save up and buy this.

Answer (score 3):

What you won't find on the Microsoft site, but on Wikipedia, is a nice [Comparison Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart).

Compared to Professional, the Home Premium edition lacks:

- support for more than 16 GB of memory: start worrying about that in a few years' time
- network support in the Backup and Restore Center: not a problem if you handle your own backups
- Remote Desktop server: not a problem if you develop only locally
- some advanced disk management stuff: not a problem
- features for a company network environment: not a problem
- Windows XP mode: handy if you want to test on XP, but can be replaced by e.g. VMWare running an XP installation
- Multilingual User Interface support: handy if you want to develop and test multilingual desktop applications

In conclusion: Professional may have some additional value if you develop Windows desktop applications for a diverse audience. If not, go for Home Premium.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically asked:
[Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Home Premium, Home Basic, or Home Starter (TechNet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx)

I guess in the past there were issues with developing for IIS on XP Home, but it looks like you can install IIS 7.5 on ANY version of Windows 7, including Starter, which I am surprised to see.  I thought Starter was short of being useless for developers.

I agree with Pekka about XP Mode in Pro and Ultimate coming in handy if you need it.  Sounds like Brian is already doing it and its working fine (I'm on Vista Ultimate until next week).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The OS you use really has little to do with development, unless you're targetting something specific to a version or edition of Windows (rare).

Comment: @SLaks: That's awfully nitpicky, but I edited to adjust for it...  That being said, even different VERSIONS are typically fine, unless you're targetting something specific to one version (or edition ;) ).